# UI Thread freezes while it shouldn't be

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

In a WPF application (C#, .NET 4.0, VS 2013), the following code (called from UI thread) freezes UI thread for 1 second:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }));
})).Start();
```

The `Thread.Sleep()` is a placeholder. In actual code it will access some UI element and do some time consuming calculation. That also runs on UI thread!

Shouldn't it be run in another thread other than the UI thread? What have I missed?

Comment: You are using the dispatcher to execute the action on the UI thread and it blocks for a second.

Comment: Please do note that accessing the UI from a background thread will cause an exception. Updates to UI elements have to be done on the main thread and for that you could use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` *is designed* to push operations (via a delegate) onto the UI thread. You have *told it* to push a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` onto the UI thread, so yes: the UI thread will freeze.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> For example, a background thread that is spun off from the main UI thread cannot update the contents of a Button that was created on the UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either Invoke or BeginInvoke. Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke is asynchronous.

If you wanted to do the work in the background... *you were already on a background thread* (before calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`).

I suspect what you should be doing here is:

1. use `.Invoke` to gather values from the UI into the worker
2. do the processing on the worker
3. use `.Invoke` or `.BeginInvoke` to update the UI

Comment: Thanks. I tend to forget the purpose of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke/Invoke. :(

Answer (score 1):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke executes operations on the main thread. Use this to execute on your thread:

```
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        };
    })).Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

like Marc already said the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()  pushes all the code int the Action to the UI Thread so the code gets executed there if you want your UI to stay responsive, do the Calculations before you call Dispatcher.Begin Invoke and then set your UI Controls in the BeginInvoke.

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    int result = MyHeavyCalculation();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }));
})).Start();
```

Or have a look at [async-await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx) to execute methods asynchron and dont bother with UI threadsynchronization yourself. [Simple Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457235/WPF-with-Asynchrony-Part)